# Different treatment for single multiline parameter

Tags: c#, resharper, editorconfig

I want to enforce the first parameter to be placed on a new line if there are several parameters and not all of them are placed on a single line

this is the setting for that: `csharp_wrap_after_invocation_lpar = true`

now in a case when there is a single parameter but it spans multiple lines e.g. a ternary expression or a lambda, I prefer it to start on the same line

```
.Select(r => r.Id == Id.None
    ? new Unload()
    : new Load(r.Id));
```

instead of

```
.Select(
        r => r.Id == Id.None
            ? new Unload()
            : new Load(r.Id));
```

is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I played around and was not able to find a setting for your desired behavior. Therefore I'd say it's not possible. But of course, you can ask [JetBrains support](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66432).